# Find all solutions which satisfy the given conditions $m=9n^3+30n^2-9n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, factoring

> Let
>
> $$ m=9n^3+30n^2-9n $$
>
> where $n \in \mathbb{Q^{+}}$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z} $ . Find all solutions which satisfy the given conditions.

I thought oh, there is probably an infinite amount of solutions but anyways I jumped in to see.

Since $m \in \mathbb{Z} $, I started with the easiest case ever $m=0$

$$ 0=9n^3+30n^2-9n $$
 $$ 0=3n(3n^2+10n-3) $$

but then I realized, if  $m,n \in \mathbb{Z} $ then basically there is a lot of solutions.

I'm more interested in the case where $n \in \mathbb{Q^{+}-Z} $ but $m \in \mathbb{Z} $. I'm not sure if I'm interpreting right but that basically means that $n$ must be rational and the output which is $m$ must be an integer but how would one solve that?

Comment: For any integer value of $n$, the value of $m$ is also an integer.

Comment: @Aravind What about $n$ being a rational numbers that are not integers, are there any solutions then?

Comment: @Sorfosh that's basically my question

Comment: If $n$ is rational and $m$ is an integer then the denominator of $n$ has to be 1, 3, or 9. So you get three cases to look at.

Comment: @GerryMyerson how did you know it was 1,3 or 9

Comment: Welcome back. The Rational Root Theorem says that if a polynomial with integer coefficients (in our case, $9t^3+30t^2-9t-m$) has a rational root, then the denominator of the rational must divide the coefficient of the term of highest degree (in our case, the coefficient 9 of the $t^3$-term).

Comment: @GerryMyerson got it. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=\frac{p}{q}$ with $gcd(p,q)=1$.

Then we want $\dfrac{9p^2+30pq-9q^2}{q^3}$ to be an integer.

This implies that $q$ must divide $9p^2$, hence $q$ divides 9.

If $q=3$, then we want $p^2+10p-9$ to be divisible by 3, which happens for any $p=2$ mod 3.

If $q=9$, then we want 81 to divide $p^2+30p$ and hence divide $p+30$, so this happens for $p=6$ (mod 9).

Comment: thanks for the help. i understood it all